# TypeError: listdir() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, listdir

I'm trying to iterate through 2 folders simultaneously since i want to work on pairs of images in two different location, unfortunately listdir takes only 1 argument so it doesn't allow me to iterate through both like in lists for example. Is there some other way to do this? Thank you

```
mypath2 = os.path.join('c:\\trainstcolor2')
images2 = list()


mypath = os.path.join('c:\\trainst2')
images = list()

for item,item2 in os.listdir(mypath,mypath2):

   image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath, item))
   image2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(mypath2, item2))

   if image is not None:

       images.append(image)
       images2.append(image2)
```

Comment: `for item, item2 in zip(os.listdir(mypath), os.listdir(mypath2)):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want to use `os.listdir` *as-is* because (from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)):

> The [returned] list [of files] is in arbitrary order.

Hence, you probably want the following:

```py
images1 = sorted(os.listdir(mypath))
images2 = sorted(os.listdir(mypath2))

for item, item2 in zip(images1, images2):
    # ...
```